why GN not point at frame zero?
why GN not point at frame zero?


(1) What do you mean by "time value default" ? (2) Frame 0 result is the geometry input in the "Simulation Zone" ; the "Simulation Zone" output starts at frame 1 ; if the frame count is 0, the "simulation loop" is empty and frame 0 result is displayed (with 0 point in your case).

simulation node add a custom Property name it “time” （or something else）. I want to read and change it every frame. but i found it alway begin with 0 .so how to set a init value for it?

It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

ok.I will do it next time.

I open a new question and move question 1 to it.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/323633

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
The custom property "time" must be incremented inside the Simulation Zone for its value to change. In the following demonstration, the increment is set to 0.1 in the Add math node.

At frame 1, the nodes inside the Simulation Zone are applied once. Consequently, there is 1 point in the Point Cloud and the "time" is 0.1.

At frame 9, the nodes inside the Simulation Zone are applied 9 times. Consequently, there are 9 points in the Point Cloud and the "time" is 0.9.

To visualize the initial state without application of the Simulation Zone, the Skip button can be checked at frame 1. The same result is achieved by setting the frame number to 0.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.0+)

Side note: to recover the time controlled by the frame rate and the frame number, you can use "as it is" the output Seconds of the Scene Time node instead of incrementing a user defined timer.
