GN simulation node custom value with capture attribute at point start with 0
question
simulation node add a custom Property name it “V” （or something else）. I want to read and change it every frame. but i found it alway begin with 0 .so how to set a init value for it?


Of course the property is not changing on each frame, because you do not give it any instruction how it should change, like adding or multiplying to it. This would even work without any Capture Attribute or Store Named Attribute if you only need the value inside the Simulation Zone and not outside. And regarding your other question, the simulation will not do anything on frame 0 when the Start of the animation is set to frame 1.

First simulation node custom Property name is 'v' just label is not same with value create by Store Name Attribute.

From blow setting you can see, simulation node value init setting is work, but Capture Attribute on points get 0.

So Capture Attribute is not suit for this solution, my solution is


Why do you keep "v" as input/output of the Simulation Zone if you manage this property as a Named Attribute ?

The name "v" of the node input is of course not the same as the Named Attribute, because it is just a label, just a visual guide for you to know what it should be used for. Internally it is just a value not associated with any geometry or attribute name.

@StefLAncien meaningless, i just forget to remove it.
